# Перестал работать selenuim

Tags: python, selenium

На python'e использую selenium, раньше работало(месяц назад), но сейчас же не открывается браузер, точнее открывается и крашится, код+лог:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "D:\python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 103, in **init**
>       self.binary, timeout)
>     File "D:\python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 51, in **init**
>       self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
>     File "D:\python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
>       self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
>     File "D:\python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 98, in _wait_until_connectable
>       raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

Использую python 3.5, windows 10. Видел ответы, но они все под linux (как пример: установкой иксов, которые я не нашел под винду)

Comment: Версия браузера? На Firefox 47 selenium крашиться

Comment: Он автоматически сам обновляется, да, 47 версия. Придется откатывать ее назад? (и как?)

Comment: Откатился до 46 и все заработало!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium не работает на Firefox версии 47.0. Нужно откатить браузер до 46 версии.